# Scrollto hash in webkit

Tags: jquery, webkit

I´ve got a problem with my code only in webkit browsers...firefox, opera and IE work fine with this...

the problem is: It doens´t exactly scroll to where i want it to sroll...it just scrolls not far enough and I can´t figure out why it just doesn´t work in webkit browsers...

my url is like www.example.com/index.php#testcontent-i11

(the -i11 (-i) is there to check if last two digits are numeric, if not it´s only one number).

the following code should be there to scroll to the content on reload if someone clicked on a link refereing to a content...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;

if (url.search("#") >= 0) {
    var pos = strpos(url, '#', 0);
    //alert(pos);
    var urlN = url.substr(pos, 60);

    var target = urlN,
 $target = $(target);
 $('html, body').stop().animate({
     'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 120
 }, 1000, 'swing', function () {    
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is jQuery included? Is all the content loaded and ready?

The code looks about right, maybe try it with a time out around the function...

```
setTimeout(function() {
//Your function
}, 400);
```